# How to change cursor color/opacity permanently in vim while custom colorscheme is installed?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

Sorry, but a didn't found way to change cursor color/opacity permanently in 'similar questions' block. I mean console vim, not GUI. Now my cursor looks like this:
[image]

I've downloaded theme "lost-shrine" from https://vimcolors.com an in this theme is not very good solution about cursor color (plus my term windows is partially transparent). How can I fix it?

UPD:
I changed cursor color in term settings with more ligh color and added "set cursorline" in .vimrc so it looks more readable
[image]

Comment: What do you want the cursor to look like instead?

Comment: @mkrieger1, I want to set cursor at 80% opacity and color #CCCCCC

Comment: With your recent edit, is the problem not solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed cursor color in term settings with more ligh color and added "set cursorline" in .vimrc so it looks more readable